# what does a singleton method belong to if the metaclass method is wrongly overridden?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, singleton-methods

In the "rubymonk" and some other ruby resources, it is mentioned that when you define a singleton method on an object, under the hood, Ruby is adding this new method to the object's metaclass. right? and also there is a trick to access the metaclass and it is it:

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

foo = "I'm a string object"

def foo.shout
  puts self.upcase
end

foo.shout

p foo.metaclass.class
p foo.class.instance_methods.include? :shout
p foo.metaclass.instance_methods.include? :shout
```

and as we all expect, the result is:

```
I'M A STRING OBJECT
Class
false
true
```

and everything is ok. but what if we change the metaclass method to return `Hash` instead of `self`?

```
  class Object
      def metaclass
        class << self
          Hash
        end
      end
    end
```

and then we check these things:

```
p foo.class.instance_methods.include? :shout
p foo.metaclass.instance_methods.include? :shout
p String.instance_methods.include? :shout
p Object.instance_methods.include? :shout
p Hash.instance_methods.include? :shout
```

and yeah, all of them are false:

```
false
false
false
false
false
```

the question is, what does `shout` method belong to now? it is not the metaclass. so what is it?!

Comment: Every time you define your own `Object#metaclass` method, Matz kills a puppy. It's not a metaclass. It's not an eigenclass. It's a [singleton class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still the metaclass, you've just removed your ability to access it directly...

```
foo.instance_eval { class << self; self; end.instance_methods.include?(:shout) }
  => true
```

Answer (score 1):

`shout` still belongs to the metaclass, and you haven't even lost your ability to access the metaclass (as the other answers suggest). You've just created a useless method on `Object` called `metaclass`. That doesn't stop you from doing the following:

```
 (class << any_object_here; self; end)
```

Note that the `class << ...` syntax is core Ruby syntax and cannot be "changed" just by redefining a method.

Answer (score 0):

The `shout` method still belongs to `foo`'s metaclass, you just do not have access to it as you chose to always return `Hash` from your method. The method definition of `foo.shout` is not affected by the semantics of your `metaclass` method.